# How to convert specific format of string into double

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using `getText()` to get a string from the xpath. The string is "*500.00 /=*"  now I want to convert it into double so that I can add it, but the problem is when I am using `getText()` I am also getting "/=", so how can I exclude this extra string format

//geting amount as string

```
String actualbookfees_amount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).getText();

String WHT_amount= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).getText();

String numPlate_amount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")).getText();

String registrationfees_amount= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")).getText();

String Motor_vehicle=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")).getText();

String With_amount=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")).getText();

//converting amount in integers
double actualbookfees_amount_int = Double.valueOf(actualbookfees_amount);
double WHT_amount_int = Double.valueOf(WHT_amount);
double numPlate_amount_int = Double.valueOf(numPlate_amount);
double registrationfees_amount_int = Double.valueOf(registrationfees_amount);
double Motor_vehicle_int = Double.valueOf(Motor_vehicle);
double With_amount_int = Double.valueOf(With_amount);

double total_amount_int= actualbookfees_amount_int + WHT_amount_int+numPlate_amount_int+ registrationfees_amount_int+Motor_vehicle_int+With_amount_int;
System.out.println(total_amount_int);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by replacing your "," with "".

```
String actualbookfees_amount = "100,000.00 /=";

actualbookfees_amount = actualbookfees_amount.replace(",", "");
double actualbookfees_amount_int = Double.valueOf(actualbookfees_amount.substring(0, actualbookfees_amount.length()-2));
System.out.println(actualbookfees_amount_int);
```

Comment: it did work ,but now i have string = "100,000.00 /=" , now how can i exclude comma from the string.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do is replacing the '/=' for ''.

You could do for example:

```
double actualbookfees_amount_int = Double.valueOf(actualbookfees_amount.replace("/=", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use replaceAll() method from java.lang.String
e.g do

```
String actualbookfees_amount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).getText().replaceAll("/=","");
```

replaceAll() details: Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given **regular expression** with the given replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Double.parseDouble(String s)
```

to convert `String` value into `double`

Comment: While this does answer how to convert from `String` to `double` in general, the OP asked about how to use a specific format of string to do that, which `parseDouble` doesn't allow.